# User Preferences broken down by type

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently struggling with a complex SQL / Laravel relationship issue.

For each user, I need to set preferences. These preferences include four different types:

1. Locations
2. Competitors
3. Platforms
4. Graphs

The desired relations would be something like:

```
$user = User::find(1)
//Retrieves all user locations
$user->preferences->locations
//Retrieves all user competitors
$user->preferences->competitors
//Retrieves all user platforms
$user->preferences->platforms
//Retrieves all graphs
$user->preferences->graphs
```

I have changed the current data structure repeatedly because I've been unable to figure it out, but it looks something like this table:

- user_preferences

  - id
  - user_id

And then for each type of preference (locations, competitors, etc), another table:

- user_preferences_locations

  - user_preferences_id
  - location_id OR competitor_id, etc.

Further complicating this mess is that the four preference types don't match the tables on which they are meant to be joined to. For example, both locations and competitors need to join to a Business table that I have (their ids in that pivot table are a business id), and platforms needs to join to a service table.

My question is, how would I go about mapping out this complex relationship? Would this be a case where I use polymorphic relations? Would I need a model for each pivot table (user_preferences_location, etc.)? I'm completely overwhelmed right now and I've been struggling with how to do this for a few hours. Any help would be extremely helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my data structure slightly. I added a `user_preferences` table that really is just a primary key and a `user_id`. Then, I made my three pivot tables have a `user_preferences_id`, and then I created the model in eloquent thusly:

```
class UserPreferences extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Business::class, "user_preference_location");
    }

    public function competitors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Business::class, "user_preference_competitor");
    }

    public function platforms()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class, "user_preference_platform");
    }
}
```

Now I can access my properties via a simple `$user->preferences->locations`. It's not as clean as I'd like: for example, I'd prefer to have a single preferences table rather than the three pivots off of it, or even, have a single pivot between `user_preferences` and its types. But that's something for another day.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overthinking it. Do you really need to access the relationships via a `preferences` property? Why not just do something like this:

```
$user = User::find(1)
//Retrieves all user locations
$user->locationPreferences
//Retrieves all user competitors
$user->competitorPreferences
//Retrieves all user platforms
$user->platformPreferences
//Retrieves all graphs
$user->graphPreferences
```

What's the difference? These are just four simple "hasMany" relationships between the user model and models for each of the four different types of preferences. Then your models look like this:

```
class LocationPreference extends Model {
}

// plus classes for the other types of preferences...

class User extends Model {

    public function locationPreferences() {
        return $this->hasMany("LocationPreference");
    }

    // plus methods for the other types of preferences...
}
```

And the tables are simple:

```
CREATE TABLE location_preferences (
    id INT AUTOINCREMENT,
    user_id INT,
    -- plus whatever other fields you need
);
```

The scheme you describe at the beginning is nice - organizing all the preferences under an attribute for the model is logically very clean - but it will require some contortions to get it to work. Why not go with a simple solution which might not be as pretty?

Comment: I ended up getting it working, it required a `user_preferences` table (`id`, `user_id`), then three pivot tables built on that. Answer explaining in detail below.

Answer (score 0):

If the preferences types tables only includes ids then it seems like you only need 4 pivot tables between the users and locations, graphs etc. You could then access them thru user->locations or setup an accessor method that would return them in the desired format

```
public function getPreferencesAttribute($value)
{
    $preferences = new stdClass();
    $preferences->locations => $this->locations;
    $preferences->graphs => $this->graphs;
    return $preferences;
}
```